# CSRF session in HTML form

Tags: php, security, csrf

In CSRF form protection we use session right. Let consider if I have login PHP at the same login page. And I want to make secure my login form with CSRF.

At one page how we add two sessions. ?
One session we will start when user login and second we use at login CSRF.

How it possible. Please help to send sample demo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually it's a combination of cookies and session store. And also encryption

Comment: and you're first instinct wasn't to search for this via Google??

Comment: This is not a website to do the code for you. Show the code you already tried, explain your problems and then people will help you fixing your case. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is vague I'll take a stab at the answer. To protect yourself from CSRF here is what you need to do in principle in it's simplest form.

1. When an initial request is made on your login page where you render the login form, generate a unique token/hash server side and store it in your session or perhaps another datastore.
2. When you render the login page store this token client side either in a cookie or as a hidden form field.
3. When the user fills up the form and submits the request, First ensure the unique token is valid then authenticate the user. If the unique token doesn't match then they either tampered with the token or are trying to make post request in an automated fashion.

CSRF is most applicable for users that have logged in because if the token were to fall into wrong hands worsts things can happen. So in that case once the person has logged in for every active user session you will generate a unique token for every request to ensure that it's actually the authenticate users that making the request.

Hope this helps!